# PDE Notation Question $C^0([0,\infty), L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, but without knowing what to call it I am having trouble finding information on it. I have been readying a variety of papers on PDEs and I keep seeing the following space of functions:

\begin{equation*}
C^0([0,\infty), L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))
\end{equation*}
or in general
\begin{equation*}
C^0([0,\infty), \mathcal{S} ).
\end{equation*}

A definition of the space or a place on where I can read about it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would interpret this notation as the continuous functions from nonnegative real numbers $[0,\infty)$ to $S$, or to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in your first example.  In principle $S$ could be any topological space, but normally the space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ would have the Hilbert space topology of square integrable functions on $n$-dimensional real space.  Most authors will define or cite a reference for notation in the introductory portions of their papers.

Comment: This takes a bit of getting used to. I never really liked it, to be honest. It's usually in the context of evolution equations and the example you've written would mean a function f(x,t) were "L^2 in space, continuous in time" and so f(x,t) can be interpreted as a continuous map that takes a time $t \in [0,\infty)$ and outputs an L^2 function f( . , t)

Comment: I see, well thank you both for the explanations. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should find much about such spaces by searching for "Banach space valued function spaces".

Since you probably want that your $C^0([0,\infty),L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$ becomes a Banach space, I would interpret it as the set of countinous and *bounded* mappings $f\colon [0,\infty)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ you have the usual $L^2$-norm. Then you have the sup-norm on $C^0([0,\infty),L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

If you want a specific refrence for this space you can look up *An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations* by Renardy&Rogers (2nd edition), beginning of Chapter 11.